# Get nested class members without accessors or mutators

Tags: c++, class, unique-ptr

I have code like so:

```
template<class T>
class tree{
     class node{
        std::unique_ptr<node<T>> left;
        std::unique_ptr<node<T>> right;
        T data;
     }; 
};
```

How do I make 'left' or 'right' accessible to the tree class without accessors or mutators? Multiple solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Make left and right public.  For a class, by default, the are private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class `node` is private to `tree`, you might as well just make it a struct. If `node` will be exposed to clients, you will probably need to write accessors anyway.